# Hide/show div, what am i doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to build a gallery that loads a div with images when a button i clicked.

the problem is that when i have 2 buttons only the last images are clickable, a little hard to explain but you can try it out on my page: http://www.bravitus.com/#gallery

is it wrong having two javascrips like that

**script1**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingpriv").hide();
    $(".show_priv").show();
    $('.show_priv').click(function(){
    $(".slidingpriv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

script2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".slidinggf").hide();
    $(".show_gf").show();
    $('.show_gf').click(function(){
    $(".slidinggf").slideToggle();
    });    
});
```

html:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="container">

        <!---section--->

        <div class="center">
        <a href="#show_priv" class="show_priv">Private projects</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slidingpriv">

        <a href="pages/inasecond/inasecond.html"><div id="imgstyle" class="image"> 
        <img href="" src="img/inasecond.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt=""/></a> 
        </div>

        <a href="pages/2012/2012.html"><div id="imgstyle" class="image">
        <img src="img/2012.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt=""/> </div></a>

        <a href="pages/greenlights/greenlights.html"><div id="imgstyle" class="image">
        <img src="img/Cover-text.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt=""/> </div> </a> 

        </div>

        <!---section--->

        <div class="center">
        <a href="#show_gf" class="show_gf">Grundforløb</a>
        </div>

        <div class="slidinggf">

        <a href="pages/inasecond/inasecond.html"><div id="imgstyle" class="image"> 
        <img href="" src="img/inasecond.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt=""/></a> 
        </div>

        <a href="pages/2012/2012.html"><div id="imgstyle" class="image">
        <img src="img/2012.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt=""/> </div></a>

        <a href="pages/greenlights/greenlights.html"><div id="imgstyle" class="image">
        <img src="img/Cover-text.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt=""/> </div> </a> 

        </div>
```

css:

```
    .center{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    /*background-color:#0C3;*/
}    
    .show_priv {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    /*background-color: #99CCFF;*/

}

    .slidinggf {
    height:100%;
    /**background-color: #99CCFF;**/
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

    .show_gf {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    /*background-color: #99CCFF;*/
}
    .slidingpriv {
    height:100%;
    /**background-color: #99CCFF;**/
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Too much code, post it to jsfiddle please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n7znzf46/

Comment: Change `.slidingpriv` from `display:block` to `display:inline-block`

Comment: You really could do with some improving on that markup! You have a `<div class="center">` which is going over the top of your items. I am not going to give a quick fix because it should be re-written entirely..

Comment: thanks dominic, removing the center div fixed the clickability ;) let me rewrite a sec ;) ill se if it works ;) 

wow i gotta take a break this is a mess -.-

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using your browser developer tools which has some very easy to use tools for debugging, such as the inspect element.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

With this you can find what may be blocking your ability to click on some elements, even if you're sure they should work.

Also try to combine scripts into the same document ($(document).ready(function(){});)

Comment: I just went back and deleted the whole gallery and rewrote it all, i found some typos it seems to be working atm.